# What am I doing wrong with this negative lookahead? Filtering out certain numbers in a regex

Tags: python, regex, sublimetext3

I have a big piece of code produced by a software. Each instruction has an identifier number and I have to modify only certain numbers:

```
grr.add(new GenericRuleResult(RULEX_RULES.get(String.valueOf(11)), new Result(0,Boolean.FALSE,"ROSSO")));
grr.add(new GenericRuleResult(RULEX_RULES.get(String.valueOf(12)), new Result(0,Boolean.FALSE,"£££")));
etc...
```

Now, I am using SublimeText3 to change rapidly all of the wrong lines with this regex:

```
Of\((11|14|19|20|21|27|28|31)\)\), new Result\(
```

This regex above allowed me to put "ROSSO" (red) in each line containing those numbers. Now I have to put "VERDE" (green) in the remaining lines. My idea was to add a `?!` in the Regex to look for all of the lines *NOT CONTAINING* those numbers.

From the website [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) I get in the description of the regex:

```
Of matches the characters Of literally (case sensitive)
\( matches the character ( literally (case sensitive)
    Negative Lookahead (?!11|14|19|20|21|27|28|31)
    Assert that the Regex below does not match
       1st Alternative 11
       etc...
```

So why am I not finding the lines containing 12, 13, 14 etc?

Edit: the Actual Regex: `Of\((?!11|14|19|20|21|27|28|31)\)\), new Result\(`

Comment: Please show the actual regex you're trying with the negative look ahead.

Comment: done, thanks. I thought it was deducible by the last code section

Comment: a negative look ahead doesn't change the cursor position, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are assuming a negative look ahead changes the cursor position, it does not.

That is, a negative lookahead of the form `(?!xy)` merely verifies that the *next* two characters are not `xy`.  It does not then swallow two characters from the text.  As its name suggests, it merely *looks ahead* from where you are, without moving ahead!

Thus, if you wish to match further things beyond that assertion you must:

- negatively assert it is not `xy`;
- then consume the two characters for whatever they are;
- then continue your match.

So try something like:

```
Of\((?!11|14|19|20|21|27|28|31)..\)\), new Result\(
```

Comment: Indeed it works. Thank you very much. Any suggestion on where to study to understand more about this and the cursor concept?